# How do I change the value of the DetailPage parameter to so that it actually opens a selected page instead of just a blank page?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I am trying to get this search page in my app to work  properly. Right now, it searches through the ListView well, but the ListView does not link to the other pages in the app. Instead, when each ListView element is tapped, it just brings up a blank page. I think I made a mistake in how I structure the DetailPage class, but I am not sure how to fix it.

[This is the code for Search.cs.](https://gist.github.com/EricGrahamMacEachern/57009becb2081e17ef45a10f4304401e)

[This is a Xamarin forum post where I have been discussing this problem. Someone has helped me and they have been very helpful so far.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79495/how-do-i-make-a-searchbar-for-a-listview-containing-contentpage-classes#latest)

I have been searching around for answers in the MSDN, but I have not been able to figure it out yet. How do I change the value of the DetailPage parameter to so that it actually opens a selected page instead of just a blank page?

This is the DetailPage class.

```
class DetailPage : ContentPage
{                
    public DetailPage(pageList page_list)
    {
        this.page_list = page_list;
    }       

    public pageList page_list { private set; get; }

}
```

This is where it the DetailPage object detailPage gets its parameter itemSelected. It just opens a blank page, which is not what I want.

```
        listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, args) =>
         {

             var itemSelected = args.Item as pageList;
             if (itemSelected != null)
             {
                 DetailPage detailPage = new DetailPage(itemSelected);
                 await Navigation.PushAsync(detailPage, true);                                     

             }

         };
```

Comment: the code snippet you posted for your DetailPage doesn't show any content, so it will naturally display as an empty page.  Is there more code (or XAML) that you haven't shown?

Comment: On the [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/EricGrahamMacEachern/57009becb2081e17ef45a10f4304401e) I posted, the Detail page accepts a parameter that is supposed to link to other existing pages in the app. The pageListings object contains the links to other pages.

Comment: there is no code in DetailPage that actually does anything with that parameter

Comment: what is Anaphylaxis (and the other items in pagelist)?  Are they ContentPages?

Comment: You are right about nothing doing anything with that parameter. Yes they are ContentPages. I think the mistake I made was that I never bound the fileName property to the ListView, so it just shows the pageList pageTitle without the fileName link to the other ContentPage. I can't figure out how to bind it properly now.

Comment: why do you even need DetailPage if you really just want to navigate to Anaphylaxis?  Why not just instantiate that and navigate directly to it?

Comment: I tried direct methods before making DetailPage, but they didn't work. When I try to get Navigation.PushAsync to use the fileName parameter in the pageListings ObservableCollection it just throws errors. "itemSelected is a variable but is used like a type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you know the Type of the page, you can use Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate it

```
         var itemSelected = args.Item as pageList;
         if (itemSelected != null)
         {
             var page = (ContentPage) System.Activator.CreateInstance(itemSelected.fileName);
             await Navigation.PushAsync(page, true);                                     
         }
```

Comment: For await Navigation.PushAsync(page, true); the error message is Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Thank you so much Jason. I was putting the cast on the wrong side. Now everything works properly. I will give you credit here, on reddit, and on the Xamarin Forums for your solution.